# Applying same wallpaper on several clients using Group Policy not working

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I have a 2 domain controllers.

The clients can login to the AD normally and everything works fine.

I want to accomplish the task of unifying all the Desktop Wallpaper Backgrounds of all the user and put the logo of the company. However it is not working.

Below is an image of how I am trying to accomplish the needed outcome:

[image: gp]

Unfortunately, it is not working.
Any ideas? Also, does it have to do anything with having a second domain controller? (which by the way, gets the users and groups replicated correctly)

Comment: Does the image file you're specifying at C:\bk.jpg exist on all of the client machines?

Comment: @joeqwerty no. It only exists on the server? It should be in all C drives of the clients also?

Comment: Yes. The path in the GPO is the local path of the machine applying the GPO, not the DC. The image file needs to be on every machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with GPOs not applying the way you think they should, the best way to diagnose this is by using the 'Group Policy Results Wizard' in the Group Policy Management app.

Start the wizard, and point it to a machine of the a user who isn't getting the background and select the relevant user.  The results wizard will display 3 major things:

- List which policies tried to run last time they were evaluated (highlights issues with user/computer ou assignment or caching)
- Display policy evaluation, including which policies will 'win' when they clash based on priorities (are multiple policies fighting, are there permissions issues)
- The logs from previous attempts to apply policies (why did the policy fail to run, assuming the first two showed no problems)

If the issue doesn't show up after working your way through those steps, it's usually caused by some sort of process or understanding issue.  For example, did you actually copy the file to that location on each machine first, as that path is local to machine running the policy, not where it is written.  You can use GPO to deploy files from DC DFS or network shares to the machine, but you need to be aware of authentication issues.  IE if it is a computer policy, the computer must be able to access that share without a user's grants.

Remember you can force refresh GPO's on the users machines using 'gpupdate /force', as GPO's aren't applied immediately.  Logs will show up in the results tool, after a refresh.